# Sinon: spy turning stub

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, sinon, stub, spy

I'm writing integration tests and want to simulate errors in underlying calls.

I know how to do it with sandboxing internal calls, but I want to do some blackbox testing without using Sinon's sandbox on internals but on passed parameters.

I want my Redis client to throw an error in one of the subsequent calls.
First time a code should call real Redis client's function. But second call to the same function should lead to an error.

I think that it should behave like a spy turning to a stub.

Is there any Sinon's feature that I don't see?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I a need conditional [stub](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) made with `stub.withArgs(arg1[, arg2, ...]);`